# Error while plotting the waterfall chart with empty dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a waterfall chart in working condition. However when the dataframe is empty it returns error. The dataframe can be empty when there is no data for the specified condition.

Below is the code I am using to plot waterfall chart. Instead of error I would like to print" The specified report does not have data"

```
#dataset <- data.frame(TotalHeadcount = c(-417, -12, 276, -276, 787, 14), Category =  LETTERS[1:6])
dataset <- data.frame(TotalHeadcount = NA, Category =  NA)[numeric(0), ]
dataset
dataset$SortedCategory <- factor(dataset$`Category`, levels = dataset$`Category`)
dataset$id <- seq_along(dataset$TotalHeadcount)
dataset$type <- ifelse(dataset$TotalHeadcount > 0, "in",   "out")
dataset[dataset$SortedCategory %in% c("A", "F"), "type"] <- "net"
dataset$type <- factor(dataset$type, levels = c("out", "in", "net"))
dataset$end <- cumsum(dataset$`TotalHeadcount`)
dataset$end <- c(head(dataset$end, -1), 0)
dataset$start <- c(0, head(dataset$end, -1))
dataset$value <-dataset$`TotalHeadcount`
library(ggplot2)
strwr <- function(str) gsub(" ", "\n", str)
ggplot(dataset, aes(fill = type))+ geom_rect(aes(x = SortedCategory,  xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end,   ymax = start))+ scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(dataset$SortedCategory), labels = strwr(levels(dataset$SortedCategory)))+ theme_bw()+ theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))+guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Here I have commented the actual dataframe data which works fine. Instead of that I have added an empty dataframe and this code gives error.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want to show the your error message? Does this work?

```
if(nrow(dataset) == 0) {
  print("The specified report does not have data")
} else {
  ggplot(dataset, ...
}
```

Comment: in place of chart, I would like to show the Message.

Comment: This does not print the message where I am plotting the chart. However it prints the message in the console which I don't want.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve this issue. Instead of print statement, I am using empty plot to show a custom text message.